# Can I read a trained linear model from s3, without reconstructing a local copy?

Tags: amazon-s3, pickle, dask, boto, joblib

In order to run a dask pipeline on a coiled cluster that uses a previously trained linear model in each task, I believe I need to read the model directly from S3. Reading the model within a task did work on a local cluster, when trying to run the code on a coiled cluster however, this did not work unfortunately.

First I saved the model to S3 using:

```css
def save_model_s3(
    model: linear_model,
    filename: str,
    path: str,  #'name/product=models/model/'
):

    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

    location = path
    model_filename = f"{filename}.pkl"  # .pkl or .sav
    OutputFile = location + model_filename

    # WRITE
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
        joblib.dump(model, fp)
        fp.seek(0)
        # use bucket_name and OutputFile - s3 location path in string format.
        s3.Bucket("bucket-name").put_object(Key=OutputFile, Body=fp.read())

    return None
```

Within the pipeline-tasks I then try to read the .sav/.pkl file. The only thing that worked for me so far is to read the file using the following code, however this doesn't seem to be working within a task on a coiled cluster.

```css
def read_joblib(path):
    ''' 
       Function to load a joblib file from an s3 bucket.
       Arguments:
       * path: an s3 bucket or local directory path where the file is stored
       Outputs:
       * file: Joblib file loaded
    '''

    # Path is an s3 bucket
    s3_bucket, s3_key = path.split('/')[2], path.split('/')[3:]
    s3_key = '/'.join(s3_key)
    with BytesIO() as f:
        boto3.client("s3").download_fileobj(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_key, Fileobj=f)
        f.seek(0)
        file = joblib.load(f)
    
    return file
```

Is there a smart way to do this in a different fashion, so that there is no need to reconstruct a local copy?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean? You have an error? Please specify.

Comment: I couldn't tell you. The kibana dashboard only returns: "No results displayed because all values equal 0". The error I believe is that I cannot use local files in a coiled task.

Comment: Suggests it did load, but the values were 0, no? You do not seem to be using local files, so I don't understand your comment.